# Question about reexpressing the dot product

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, 3d

Suppose that I have two arbitrary 3-dimensional vectors, $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$.  By the definition of the dot product, I can write

$$\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} = \left|\vec{a}\right| \left|\vec{b}\right| \cos \theta$$

I can solve for $\cos \theta$:

$$\cos \theta = \frac{\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}}{\left|\vec{a}\right| \left|\vec{b}\right|}$$

My question is, is it correct to  rewrite $\cos \theta$ in terms of the unit vectors $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{b}$ as follows?

$$\cos \theta = \frac{\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}}{\left|\vec{a}\right| \left|\vec{b}\right|}$$
$$\cos \theta = \frac{\vec{a}}{\left|\vec{a}\right|} \cdot \frac{\vec{b}}{\left|\vec{b}\right|}$$
$$\boxed{\cos \theta = \hat{a} \cdot \hat{b}}$$

where $\hat{a} = \frac{\vec{a}}{\left|\vec{a}\right|}$ and $\hat{b} = \frac{\vec{b}}{\left|\vec{b}\right|}$.

In other words, is it correct to reexpress the dot product in that way?  Thanks for your time.

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: That is not usually the definition of the dot-product. The definition is $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}=a_1b_1+ \cdots + a_nb_n$ for you $n=3$ then the Cauchy Schwarz inequality allows one to define angle by essentially that formula. Alternatively, the formula is a consequence of the definition and the Law of Cosines. But the connection between the formula adding cartesian components and the formula you call the definition requires some effort.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. You can get this result from your definition:

$$\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}=|\vec{a}||\vec{b}|\cos\theta$$

If you consider $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ to be unit vectors, then $|\vec{a}|=|\vec{b}|=1,$ and the expression becomes:

$$\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}=\cos\theta,$$ where $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ are unit vectors.